# Al dar onChange en un input pasar el target del evento como parámetro de una función

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito al dar onChange en un input pasar el taget del evento como parámetro de una función. Estoy intentando hacer esto pero al hacer el debugger veo que no está entrando a la función:

```
<input type="date" value={from} onChange={e => this.handleChangeInputDateFrom(e.target.value)}
```

Esta es la función:

```
   handleChangeInputDateFrom = from => () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        filters: {
          ...state.filters,
          from: from
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que propone @Riven es valida. Pero para que sepas porque no te funciona tu código actual te explico.

En tu código estas usando una `Higher Order Function(Función de orden superior)` es una función que recibe una función como parámetro o retorna una función. Y es tu caso retornas una.

Se usan bastante en JS para encapsular datos y crear closures para recordar scopes(ámbitos). En tu caso, no aporta mucho hacer esto porque solo quieres setear el nuevo valor.

Cuando llamas `onChange={this.handleChangeInputDateFrom()}` estas devolviendo la función de dentro que se usará como referencia en el `onChange` y recibirá como parámetro el evento.

Pero para que te funcione tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```html
<input type="date" value={from} onChange={this.handleChangeInputDateFrom()} />
```

```
handleChangeInputDateFrom = () => (e) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
        filters: {
        ...state.filters,
        from: e.target.value
        }
    }
};
```

Esto sin arrow functions sería así. No lo hagas así porque podrias llegar a perder la referencia al `this`.

```
handleChangeInputDateFrom = function(){ 
   return function (e) {
    this.setState(state => ({
        filters: {
        ...state.filters,
        from: e.target.value
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Gracias:ya vote por tu respuesta pero no me aparece aún.

Comment: ya se ve. Me alegro que te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion:

[Manejando eventos](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

No requieres hacer todo eso para pasarle un evento como parametro a la funcion, ya que segun la documentacion se le es pasado automaticamente si lo declaras de esta manera:

```
<input type="date" value={from} onChange={handleChangeInputDateFrom}>
```

Y simplemente recibes el parametro para poder usarlo en tu funcion:

```
handleChangeInputDateFrom = ev => {

   //Puedes usar ev directamente donde desees ahora en esta funcion.
   this.setState(state => ({
     filters: {
        ...state.filters,
        from: from
     }
   }
};
```

Que por cierto, no entendi muy bien la estructura de tu funcion `handleChangeInputDateFrom` original, puesto que parecia una funcion flecha mal estructurada, pero pues no uso `react`, quiza eso en `react` sea valido, pero hasta donde se una funcion flecha deberia ser asi:

```
handleChangeInputDateFrom = ev => {
```

Y **NO** asi:

```
handleChangeInputDateFrom = from => () => {
```

Que era como la tenias.

por cierto, note que aqui:

```
onChange={e => this.handleChangeInputDateFrom(e.target.value)}
```

Estabas usando `this`, recuerda que como se trata de `HTML` cuando usas `this` te estaras refiriendo es al elemento `HTML` en si y no al componente lo cual supongo que es lo que deseas, usar `this` para tu caso no es buena idea, puesto que dudo que ese elemento `HTML` tenga un metodo llamado `handleChangeInputDateFrom`, en tu caso debes apuntar es al componente y **NO** al elemento **HTML**.

Comment: tal cual has dicho NO usas ReactJS,  el compañero esta en lo correcto al usar "this" en el evento onChange este es parte de ReactJS y no del Elemento HTML, por lo que el this esta haciendo referencia al componente que esta creando, si no colocara el this, tronaría el asunto y no funcionara.

Comment: Vale, gracias por el aporte, es bueno saberlo, de todas maneras tocara esperar al usuario a ver que tal, aunque se me hace raro, puesto que en la documentacion oficial no usan this para ese proposito.

Comment: Ya vi la documentacion que enlazas, si haces un poco de scroll veras que cuando NO usa THIS  se esta utilizando una función, mas abajo te hace la mencion del uso de ES6 donde se utilizan clases, el uso de funciones es algo usado generalmente (hasta donde he visto) para integrar ReactJS en proyectos ya desarrollados donde solo quieres una pequeña parte con react, cuando creas un nuevo proyecto totalmente en react, se utilizan clases, dan mayor control y flexibilidad

Comment: Exacto,  tal cual lo haz dicho.